# Microsoft Graph Api, Groups : how to get Mentions or Likes of a conversation thread?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to get more properties from a conversation's group via Graph Api.

If I call :

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{groupId}/conversations/{conversationId}](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/conversations/%7BconversationId%7D)

I get something like that :

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#groups('{GroupId}')/conversations/$entity",
"id": "{ConversationId}",
"topic": "{Subject}",
"hasAttachments": true,
"lastDeliveredDateTime": "2021-03-12T12:41:27Z",
"uniqueSenders": [
    "{Sender}"
],
"preview": "‍{Message}"}
```

But in outlook i have some other properties :
Categories, Mentions, Likes

How to get them ?

Comment: You can try the following API call and it works for me:

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/AQMkADJmMTUAAAgVZAAAA/?$expand=mentions

Comment: The above example shows getting the details of all the mentions in the specified message in the logged one users (me) mailbox. Try the above and let me know if it works.